# HERE Maps Directions limitation

Tags: directions, here-maps-rest

It looks that HERE Maps Direction resource is returning legs between two waypoints only. If I add more waypoints then it will be ignored by the API. Limitation?

Comment: Question needs more details.. such abstract questions are very difficult to answer.

Comment: Regardless if I add waypoint2, waypoint3 etc. the Directions will be from waypoint0 to waypoint1 only. Is it a limitation?